# Can't read data from file into a linked list

Tags: c

Ok I have already managed to solve my problem, thanks to all who replied. Turns out in this code I'm allocating memory in the wrong place, I should be allocating inside the 'for' loop so that the data is not overwritten

```
void getdata (int counter){
    int i = 0;
    user_t* temp = NULL, * ptr = NULL;
    //temp = (user_t*)malloc(sizeof(user_t)); this is what I was doing
    FILE *varfile;  
    varfile = fopen ("data.txt", "r");
    if (varfile==NULL) {
        printf("Error");
        return;
    }
    else { 
        for (i = 0; i < counter; i++){
            temp = (user_t*)malloc(sizeof(user_t)); //and this is where I should be allocating
            fscanf (varfile, "%d %s %s %s %d %d %d %f", &temp->id, temp->name, temp->birth_place, temp->work_place, &temp->prof_obj, &temp->academics, &temp->hobby, &temp->salary);
            temp->prox = NULL; 
            if (start == NULL) {
                start = temp;
            }
            else {
                ptr = start;
                while (ptr->prox != NULL) {
                    ptr = ptr->prox;
                }
            ptr->prox = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    fclose (varfile);
    return;
}
```

Comment: Crashes *where* in the while loop?

Comment: 1. You never check the file actually opened successfully. 2, your "targets" in scanf need `&` 3. Why use temp variables? Why not `scanf` directly to the final target?

Comment: @John3136 I have already implemented an if statement to check if the file opens, thanks. Just added '&' to all int and float variables and still crashes. And the last point, I have also tried to use fscanf directly to the final target, but still crashed in the same spot.

Comment: You need to change `name` etc to `char name[64]` or similar so you've actually got somewhere to read the name into. You should also show the struct definition - does the struct have space for the name or just a pointer that isn't set?

Answer (score 0):

There are some obvious problems with your code.

First off we don't know what `user_t` looks like.
If it is like

```
typedef struct user {
    ...
    char* name;
    ...
} user_t;
```

Then `temp = (user_t*)malloc(sizeof(user_t));` doesn't actually give you any space for the name - you would need another malloc (or use `strdup` instead of `strcpy`) or put the space straight into the struct:

```
typedef struct user {
    ...
    char name[64];
    ...
} user_t;
```

Next: lines like this shouldn't even compile: `char name = "";` as the types are wrong. The variable is of type char but you are assigning a string to it. `char* name = "";` would compile but is still wrong. You are using these variables as buffers to read a string into. You need space to store the string. `char name[64];` will do - but obviously you need the size to be bigger than your biggest expected name.

Next: You never check the `malloc` or `fopen` worked - both could potentially fail. Sure the malloc isn't likely to fail, but the file open might - continuing on when either one has failed is undefined behavior.

Next: `scanf` needs the address of where to read to, so should be like `fscanf(fp, "%d %s %s %s %d %d %d %f", &id, name, birth_place, work_place, &prof_obj, &academics, &hobby, &salary);` Note the string buffers are already addresses so you don't need the ampersand on them.

You can avoid the use of temporary variables and string copies by reading straight into "temp": `fscanf(fp, "%d %s %s %s %d %d %d %f", &temp->id, temp->name, temp->birth_place, temp->work_place, &temp->prof_obj, &temp->academics, &temp->hobby, &temp->salary);` (note this assumes you've addressed the first issue about the struct.

Comment: Thanks, but now I have another problem, when I have 2 users and I try to list them, the program spams the second user details, without even showing the first 1. My 2 functions now look like in the post

Comment: One question per question. This is not interactive community debugging!